# How to get alf_ticket in Alfresco Share 3.4

Tags: javascript, share, alfresco

I've been using `context.properties.alfTicket` to get a ticket for some custom stuff I've been working before, but recently I migrated from Alfresco 3.0 to 3.4.

Now I can't find the authentication ticket in Alfresco Share - is there a way to get this? Whether in JavaScript (server-side, of course) or freemarker.

Edit: I added a bounty. I'll give the bounty to whoever gives me the code sample on how to get the `alf_ticket` in `document-details.get.js` or `document-details.get.html.ftl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an Alfresco webscript you could use `session.ticket`, this should be available in Share to. This link to the [alfresco 3.4 javascript api](http://www.alfresco.com/help/34/enterprise/api/) could also be useful, I don't think this is references anywhere on the alfresco site.

Comment: Although I solved this some other way I still wanted to check. But it didn't seem to work: Caused by: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression session is undefined on line 17, column 41 in org/alfresco/components/dashlets/test-dash.get.html.ftl.

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest Template Guide : http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Template_Guide

The session.ticket should be available in the Freemarker Template.